# Converting Strings to longs

Tags: java, string, long-integer

How would I iterate through an array and attempt to convert a string to a long? This is an example below:

```
String[] myArray = ["123", "122 Street", "2334"];
    // I'm trying to loop through an array like this and cast to a long
for(String s: myArray) {
  try {
   long newValue = Long.valueOf(s);
   // How would I swap the old values to their new long type in the 
   // myArray?
    } catch(Exception error) { }
 }
```

Comment: what would you expect when you try to convert "122 Street" into a Long ?

Comment: I wouldn't expect to convert it because it has "Street" within it. In this case, wouldn't I be catching it and continuing?

Comment: You can't store longs in an array of type String[]. Such an array can only contain Strings.

Comment: Raising and catching exceptions as part of the program *normal* flow is bad practice! A better way to do it would be to validate first if the string contains only digits and only then trying to parse it as Long. Example: `"122 Street"".matches("\\d+")` will return `false` while `"123"".matches("\\d+")` will evaluate to `true`

Comment: Ok, so what would be a better approach to what I'm trying to to?

Comment: I'm new to Java, and a beginner fyi.

Comment: Create a new array of type Long, and push/add elements there.

Comment: I would like to keep one array and iterate over it, turn any Strings I can to longs and update the old array. Could I accomplish this with an ArrayList instead?

Comment: @ctaz1001 no you can't: Java is strongly typed so once you declared an array as "array of strings" you cannot re-use it to occupy objects of any other type, Long included. The "waste" in space is, in most cases, something you shouldn't worry about.

Comment: Do you want 122 from "122 Street", or do you want to discard that one?

Comment: @Bohemian I would ignore that one and move on.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot put a `long` into a `String[]`. You'd need to create a second array specifically for holding the longs. I'm unsure whether "122 Street" would cast correctly or give an error.

```
String[] myArray = ["123", "122 Street", "2334"];
long[] longs = new long[myArray.length];
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  try {
    longs[i] = Long.valueOf(myArray[i]);
  } catch (Exception e) {
    // Handle error case
  }
}
```

Comment: You would be better off with `Long[]` because it lets you keep `null`s. Other than that it's a good answer, I don't understand the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Java arrays only store the type they were declared to store (Java ain't JavaScript).

Here's a 1-liner:

```
long[] numbers = Arrays.stream(myArray)
    .filter(s -> s.matches("\\d+"))
    .mapToLong(Long::parseLong)
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Nice! I've been away from java for a while. Seems there are some new tricks I've missed since then. +1

Answer (score 0):

1. before converting a string to long, I'd validate that it has only digits in order to avoid exceptions which are very costly in Java (unlike other languages such as Python in which raising and catching exceptions is perfectly normal).
2. Since we have no way of knowing what will be the size of the new array, and having array that contains `null`s is not ideal, we can work with a `List` to collect the results and when we're done - convert it into an array of `Long`

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] myArray = {"123", "122 Street", "2334"};
    Long[] array = stringsToLongs(myArray);
}

private static Long[] stringsToLongs(String[] myArray) {

    List<Long> list = new LinkedList<>();
    for(String s: myArray) {
        if (s.matches("\\d+"))
            list.add(Long.valueOf(s));
    }
    return list.toArray(new Long[list.size()]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alfasin for explaining that to me. I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

> How would I swap the old values to their new long type in the myArray?

**You wouldn't.** Your array is already of `Type` of `string`. It can only accept `string` values. If you want an *equivalent* array of type `long`, you will need exactly that. A different array, of that type; with equivalent values stored inside.

---

Other answers are not technically correct in their current wording. One ***can*** put a `long` *value* in a `string[]` array; ***just not in a `long` type/format***.

The same applies in reverse (which is what you seem to want to do): You can have `long[]` holding data that was previously in `string` type/format. You just need to do the proper conversion.

---

Another thing other answers get slightly wrong, is that there is technically no *casting*, in the true meaning of the word, between numerical types and strings. What is done instead is called ***parsing***.

In the case of your issue specifically, parsing a `long` value from it's `string` representation is done using [`long.valueOf(string s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

Note that this method expects a `string` representation of a number, and will fail with [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) with something else.

This includes `"122 Street"`. That's not a number. `"122"` is. So you'll have to parse `"122"` out of the rest of the string first, before converting that to `long`.

---

Solution:

```
String[] myArray = ["123", "122 Street", "2334"];
myArray[1] = myArray[1].substring(0,2); //Removes " Street" from second element.
long[] myLongs = new long[myArray.length];
for(int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
    try {
        myLongs[i] = Long.valueOf(myArray[i]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        System.out.println("Element at index "+i+" could not be parsed.");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Some other exception happened.");
    }
}
```